# Would my unspayed female GSD be at greater risk of cancer if she is not mated?

Tags: dogs, health, german-shepherd

Well I have 3 year GSD female. She's very healthy. She's not spayed. 
I want to know that is it true that if my dog doesn't get mated/reproduce a baby she will have cancers. Is it true?

I just don't want puppies, well the fact is I can't take care anymore. I don't want to be inhuman and sell the puppies to someone. She haven't mated never yet. Please tell me will she have cancer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unspayed female dogs are actually at a higher risk of mammary tumors (breast cancer) than spayed dogs. As with any type of cancer, there is no guarantee that an unspayed dog will develop it or that a spayed dog will never develop it.

Here you can read more: https://m.petmd.com/dog/conditions/cancer/c_dg_mammary_gland_tumor

> Benign and malignant tumors of the mammary glands occur fairly frequently in unspayed female dogs, in fact they are the most common type of tumor in the group. Spaying can largely reduce the risk of developing this type of cancer, especially if the dog is spayed before it has an opportunity to go into heat.
>
> A genetic basis is possible in some breeds, and there are frequently some genes that can be identified in dogs that are predisposed to cancer of the mammary glands. For example, [...] German shepherd dogs, Maltese, and Yorkshire terriers have been reported to have an increased risk of developing breast or mammary tumors compared to other breeds.

**Edit**

Mario is right, the actual act of mating or reproduction has no influence on the risk of cancer. Dogs in heat produce a lot of hormones. In females these hormones often cause the production of milk, even if she didn't mate. That is probably what causes the breast cancer.

Spaying a female dog prevents the production of hormones, so she doesn't go into heat anymore.

Comment: So you saying that let my pet mate at least once will decrease the chance that she will have a cancer?

Comment: @KillerMomo Err, no, this has nothing to do with mating. It's a hormone thing.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know that is it true that if my dog doesn't get
>   mated/reproduce a baby she will have cancers.

There is no guarantee she will, but like everything there are risks to both sides.

The risk of mammary cancer is small, but increases with every season if left in tact after 30 months old. But... spaying opens the door to a host of other cancers and issues. So there is a risk either way.

Also its worth noting that there is a lower risk of a bitch getting pyrometra if she has a litter. There’s only a 1% chance of a dog dying from pyometra though. I wouldn't condone having a litter as the risk isnt reduced enough to warrant it.

For further reading on long term health risks associated to spaying [see here](https://www.dogsnaturallymagazine.com/long-term-health-risks-benefits-spay-neuter-dogs/).